# Automator - Parsing XML in URL to variable (or dictionary)

Tags: xml, parsing, applescript, automator

First post here!

I know how to code a little, but please regard me as a total newb.

I'm trying to do an Automator action (Mac) that reads a XML from a URL (URL never changes) and parses it.

The XML has a lot of data, but my interest is in two specific values, the "Name" and a stored "URL" specific for that name.

This is an example of the XML looks like:

```
<jobs>
    <jobad>
        <id>54844</id>
        <title>HR Manager</title>
        <text>Random text</text>
        <location>City, State</location>
        <expiration/>
        <url>https://url/jobs/43395.58958.54844</url>
        <application>
            https://url/jobs/43395.58958.54844.1
        </application>
</jobad>
<jobs>
    <jobad>
        <id>54847</id>
        <title>Sales Manager</title>
        <text>Random text</text>
        <location>City, State</location>
        <expiration/>
        <url>https://url/jobs/43395.58958.54847</url>
        <application>
            https://url/jobs/43395.58958.54847.1
        </application>
</jobad>
```

I don't need most of the information.  I basically just need the `<title>` and the `<url>`.

The idea is to parse the XML, add it into a dictionary where I can make a menu, that shows all the `<title>` values, have the user select which one they want, and return the `<url>` of the selected `<title>`.

I've tried to parse on different ways but failed because I don't know applescript that well.  Also, it doesn't have to be a dictionary, any variable that does the job will do.  This is just what I've tried.

I do have the code up and running for the menu and the return of the selected item.

It is the XML parsing that's breaking my head.

Thanks in advace!

Comment: Hello. Did you try these methods ? https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/WorkwithXML.html

Comment: I did try the example.  However, I was not able to make Applescript "find" the "Book Data.xml" file when I tried it out.  I was trying it out to at least being able to parse any xml file, then figure out how to have the file be in an URL instead in the HD.  But again, no luck.

Comment: Here is what I tried:
1) copied the XML example on TextEdit and saved it as "Book Data.xml" and moved it to Desktop
2) Made a new Automator file > AppleScript and added the AppleScript example.
3) Hit run to try it out, but gave the error that the file was not found.

Answer (score 0):

OK then, first, your example XML is malfomed, the jobs tag doesn't close. I assume it's this way and saved on the desktop as "Jobs.xml" :

```
<jobs>
    <jobad>
        <id>54844</id>
        <title>HR Manager</title>
        <text>Random text</text>
        <location>City, State</location>
        <expiration/>
        <url>https://url/jobs/43395.58958.54844</url>
        <application>
            https://url/jobs/43395.58958.54844.1
        </application>
    </jobad>
    <jobad>
        <id>54847</id>
        <title>Sales Manager</title>
        <text>Random text</text>
        <location>City, State</location>
        <expiration/>
        <url>https://url/jobs/43395.58958.54847</url>
        <application>
            https://url/jobs/43395.58958.54847.1
        </application>
    </jobad>
</jobs>
```

and the script might be :

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell XML file "~/Desktop/Jobs.xml"
        tell XML element "jobs"
            set myJobs to {}
            set jobads to every XML element whose name = "jobad"
            repeat with thisJOb in jobads
                set myTitle to (value of first XML element of thisJOb whose name = "title")
                set myUrl to (value of first XML element of thisJOb whose name = "url")
                set the end of myJobs to {myTitle, myUrl}
            end repeat
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
return myJobs
```

the result is :

```
{{"HR Manager", "https://url/jobs/43395.58958.54844"}, {"Sales Manager", "https://url/jobs/43395.58958.54847"}}
```